# How to render a view to a string?

Tags: javascript, view, rendering, sails.js

I want to render a specific view in a sailsjs controller/action which should be sent out as email.

I have the following sample action:

```
function registerAction(req, res) {
   // handle user registration


  // email user
  sendEmail({
      to: newUser.email,
      subject: "Welcome",
      text: /* VIEW RENDER HERE */
  });

  // render view to the user
  return res.view({
     user: newUser
  });
}
```

How can I render a view-template with the tools sailsjs provides so that I don't need to hardcode an email text or use other libraries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express' [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) is still [accessible](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/controllers.md#resviewview-options-fn) in your `res` object.

```
function registerAction(req, res) {
   // handle user registration

  res.render('/path/to/view', function (err, html) {
    // email user
    sendEmail({
        to: newUser.email,
        subject: "Welcome",
        text: html
    });
  }

  // render view to the user
  return res.view({
     user: newUser
  });
}
```

Comment: When I use this, it only works if you pass the name of the view, not the path.

My html is also not rendered in the callback.  My variables inside the ejs template aren't filled in, they still show as `{{ person.name }}`.  Is there anything special that needs to be done?

Comment: @Brandon I probably erroneously assumed `res.render()` accepts a path instead of a "view name". It doesn't change much though. However you get the "view name" is up to your app's logic. As for rendering "unfilled templates", you either need to compile your template on the server and serve it, or serve it and have a client-side library (e.g. AngularJS, ReactJS etc.) interpret the template, or both.

Comment: Brandon to pass in variables, the second parameter should be your data, e.g. res.render('path/to/view', { name: person_name }, function(err, html)... etc.

Comment: Also the parameter to sendEmail should be 'html', rather than 'text'

Answer (score 0):

To improve a little on crzrcn's answer, to ensure

```
function registerAction(req, res) {
   // handle user registration

  // don't include the .ejs of the end of your view, this assumes a file in path/to/view.ejs
  res.render('path/to/view', function (err, html) {
    // email user
    sendEmail({
        to: newUser.email,
        subject: "Welcome",
        html: html // rather than text in crzrcn's answer
    });
  }

  // render view to the user
  return res.view({
     user: newUser
  });
}
```