# How to render a view into a string in SailsJS?

Tags: sails.js, ejs

In one controller I want to render a certain view with a certain layout to send an email with the resulting string, but I obviously do not need to show the result to the user. Is there a way to use the EJS engine that I'm using to render views to achieve this? Here's my a bit simplified controller action:

```
  setEmail: function(req, res) {
    var update = {
      activationToken: _getToken(),
      email: req.param('email')
    };

    Profile.update(res.locals.profile.id, update).then(function(profile) {
      res.redirect(profileUrl);
      mailer.sendActivationEmail(
        update.email,
        res.i18n('Подтвердите свой адрес электронной почты'),
        emailString); // <=== Here is where I need the string rendered from a view
    });
  },
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render specific views in sailsjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325608/how-to-render-specific-views-in-sailsjs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the view-hook

```
Profile.update(res.locals.profile.id, update).then(function(profile) {
  res.redirect(profileUrl);

  sails.hooks.views.render("viewname",profile, function(err,html){
     if(err) return console.log(err);

     mailer.sendActivationEmail(
       update.email,
       res.i18n('Подтвердите свой адрес электронной почты'),
       html
     );
    })

});
```

Edit: right callback

Comment: That is very interesting! But the docs say that the hooks API is still unstable: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Plugins/Hooks
Can you please provide a link to where the available hooks are documented?

Comment: Yes thats true - the API ist unstable. That is because the hole sails-framework ist only at 0.10 beta (far awary from stable 1.0). Currently there isn't a list of available Hooks at the docs. You can look at /node_modules/sails/lib/hooks

Answer (score 2):

I think I would rather use a specific email module like this one:

https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates

Which can access EJS templates