# Return rendered ejs view as html string inside service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I have a service in my sails app that emails the user an activation form. I'm using [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) to send the email, but I have to stick in a messy html string manually.

I'm relatively new to sails and am having a hard time finding documentation on how to stick some variables into an ejs template and return an html string. I'm not sure if this is a global service in sails (like async) or I need to add a grunt task.

To be more specific this is what I need to do:

**views/emailTemplate.ejs**

```
<html>
    <h1>Hello, <%- user %></h1>
</html>
```

**services/generateEmailService.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
    var email = require("emailjs");
    ejs('views/emailTemplate.ejs', {user: "Bob"}, function(html) {
        email.send({to: "me@site.com", from: "you@site.com", html: html});
    });
};
```

And in your email's source...

```
<html>
    <h1>Hello, Bob</h1>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to solve, but using a sails hook you can initiate the view engine and render one of your views with data.

See also 
[How to render a view into a string in SailsJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187206/how-to-render-a-view-into-a-string-in-sailsjs)

`sails.hooks.view.render()`