# Render a view into HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

Is there any way to access ExpressJs's raw rendering capabilities **without access to the 'res' object**?

I have several Jade views which I'd like to render into HTML and send over email. There are libraries that do this, but all of them are clunky. Is there no `app.render("/directory/file.jade")`? I can't seem to find one.

I'm using SailsJs, which is Express based, but if there are any sails specific solutions, they would be just as helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render a view to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325608/how-to-render-a-view-to-a-string)

Comment: @ScottGress I should have added that I need a solution without using the `res` object.

Comment: Ah, well, then you can use `sails.hooks.views.render`--see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24223255/345484

Comment: I totally forgot--`sails.hooks.views.render` is now aliased to `sails.renderView`.  Fewer keystrokes!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the [`jade`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) module directly. Express doesn't really add much on top of the engine, aside from adding `res.render()`, which you said you didn't want.