# Updating ejs view in Sails.js 0.10 after receiving socket.on

Tags: websocket, sails.js

I have a MenuItemController with an index action that makes a custom query to the mongodb database then loads the view (ejs) with the returned data using    res.view({menuitems: menuitems})
Now the problem is, I want to update the ejs view in real time whenever a new menuitem is created. I already called     MenuItem.subscribe(menuitems)    . The Sails documentation shows how to subscribe to and receive websockets (http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets) but in all of the examples they only do a console.log() at the end, with no example on how to pass data to the ejs template.

I have already tried using angular instead of ejs, but am having all sorts of trouble getting things to work so I'd rather stick to vanilla Sails.js.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help others answer your question, please provide some code showing what you've tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change server-rendered `.ejs` views in real time because they are, well, rendered on the server.  That's precisely what frameworks like Angular are for.  Sails tries its best to enforce this by disallowing the use of `res.view` for Socket responses, but if you really wanted to you could:

1. use [res.render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325608/how-to-render-a-view-to-a-string) to render the view to a string.
2. end your controller action with `res.send(aWholeBunchOfHTML)`
3. use the HTML you receive from the socket response to re-render the entire page on the client.

If you're using any sort of front-end library like jQuery, you'll lose all your bindings this way, and it's a terrible waste of bandwidth that would probably make your app a bit less than "realtime".

But to reiterate, there's no way to change just a *part* of your already-rendered view using Sails.  If you're having trouble making Sails and Angular work together, I'd recommend checking out the [ActivityOverlord 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHIybLmoxfE) videocasts and [repo](https://github.com/irlnathan/activityoverlord20).

Comment: I ended up being able to get angular included in the project after several hours of headache. Thank you